# Calling platform specific method in AlarmManager

Tags: flutter, dart

I have the following situation. I have an AlarmManager which fires once a day. In this Alarm I compare two values and if these values are the same, I send an notification. So I created my Platform specific code (only Android) to send the notification.

Problem: I can call the Method only outside of the AlarmManager. That means if I call the Method "normal" without the AlarmManager, everything works as expected. Otherwise it will throw an error like this:

```
22:25:30.545 16 info flutter.tools E/flutter ( 5255): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method test on channel reminder_channel)
```

Code with AlarmManager:

main.dart

```
final int dailyAlarmID = 0;
await AndroidAlarmManager.initialize();

runApp(...);

await AndroidAlarmManager.oneShot(
    Duration(seconds: 15), dailyAlarmID, testMethod);
}
```

testMethod:

```
void testMethod() async {
  SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  bool testBool = preferences.getBool("darkTheme");
  print("testBool: $testBool");

  final MethodChannel platform = const MethodChannel("reminder_channel");
  final testInt = await platform.invokeMethod("test");
  print("testInt: $testInt");
}
```

By the way, my Method returns a single Int, which is 5. This is just for testing. And the testBool variable is read from the Shared Preferences and displayed correctly in both variants.

Output:

```
22:25:30.535 15 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 5255): testBool: true
22:25:30.545 16 info flutter.tools E/flutter ( 5255): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(148)] Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method test on channel reminder_channel)
```

Without AlarmManager:

main.dart:

```
testMethod();
```

I just call the Method at the end of the main-method. Nothing special.

Output:

```
22:41:58.054 10 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 5564): testBool: true
22:41:58.633 12 info flutter.tools I/flutter ( 5564): testInt: 5
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue of the dart as of now. 
Refer https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/56186 and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13937